# Sort folders by name in spClientContext.Load(spFOlder.Folders) and VB.NET

Tags: sharepoint-online, sorting, visual-studio-2017

I do have the folders and they are loaded correctly but they are not sorted.

```
dim spClientContext As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext
dim spFOlder As Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder

...
spClientContext.Load(spFOlder.Folders)
```

Sorry for my question, I am a newbie: How can I sort `spFolder.Folders` by name?

I need it in VB.NET.

Thanks in advance
Norman

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to sort it as any other collection of objects. This piece of code should do the work:

```
...
spClientContext.Load(spFOlder.Folders) 
spClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
Dim sorted = spFOlder.Folders.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Name)
...
```

UPDATE (code that worked in VB.NET Console Application):
... login code ommitted

Add this in the top section in the code

```
Imports System.Linq
```

Then the code below:

```
Dim web = Context.Web
Dim list = web.Lists.GetByTitle("LIST TITLE")
Dim folders = list.RootFolder.Folders
Context.Load(folders)
Context.ExecuteQuery()

Dim sorted = folders.OrderBy(Function(t) t.Name)
For Each f In sorted
    Console.WriteLine(f.Name)
Next
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I tried that but OrderBy is not defined for folders. I saw that and OrderByDescending on the net but my Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder is missing that. Do I habe to import something that I dont have yet? I looked in the docs, too, and Order by doesn't seem to be available for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder. Guess I am missing something...

Comment: OrderBy (and OrderByDescending) are extension methods from System.Linq.Queryable class and should be automatically available on FolderCollection. I've tested the code in VB.NET Console Application and it worked fine. I've updated my answer with my code so you can check if you can reuse any part of it.

Comment: Oh you are brilliant, thank you very much :) I added this: Imports System.Linq.Queryable, that did the trick. should have imported the clients stuff, probably would have worked from start then. Thanks Damjan!

Comment: Cool, now this works, too: spClientContext.Load(spFOlder.Folders, Function(folders) folders.OrderBy(Function(folder) folder.Name))

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP referred to VB in the question but I had the same issue in C# and based on @Damjan's answer this is what worked for me:

```
var sorted = folder.Folders.OrderBy(t => t.Name);
```

Also had to add

```
Using System.Linq;
```